# How to make APFS option available in disk utility?

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk

I want to reformat an external harddisk

[image]

For some reasons there is no option of APFS. How can I enbale APFS for an external harddisk?

Here is the detail of the external harddisk

```
My Passport 0837:

  Product ID:   0x0837
  Vendor ID:    0x1058  (Western Digital Technologies, Inc.)
  Version:  10.72
  Serial Number:    57999999414199999365659999
  Speed:    Up to 5 Gb/sec
  Manufacturer: Western Digital
  Location ID:  0x01100000 / 1
  Current Available (mA):   900
  Current Required (mA):    896
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
  Media:
My Passport 0837:
  Capacity: 1 TB (1,000,170,586,112 bytes)
  Removable Media:  No
  BSD Name: disk4
  Logical Unit: 0
  Partition Map Type:   MBR (Master Boot Record)
  USB Interface:    0
  Volumes:
Photo Backup 1 bad:
  Capacity: 1 TB (1,000,169,537,536 bytes)
  Available:    912.63 GB (912,629,383,168 bytes)
  Writable: Yes
  File System:  Case-Sensitive Journaled HFS+
  BSD Name: disk4s1
  Mount Point:  /Volumes/Photo Backup 1 bad
  Content:  Apple_HFS
  Volume UUID:  2254E6C8-8BB6-38B0-9153-D99C10A7B874
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Partition Map Type:   MBR (Master Boot Record)`

You need to format the entire drive, not just the partition.

APFS requires the underlying structure to be GUID, not MBR.

As only Volumes are shown by default, you need to change to Show All Devices from the View menu…

[image]